# Add Id field in StringField object in WTForms

Tags: javascript, python, flask, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am creating a form in Python using Flask and WTForms and show the form in the front end using HTML.

I want to add validation and also do a network call on the client side using JavaScript, the thing is i cannot get value in a specific field on the client side itself because there is no id supplied to the String field.

How can we do that? If thats not possible what is the alternate way

```
class Add_user_form(Form):
    name = StringField('Name',[validators.Length(min = 1, max=50)])
    email_address = StringField('Email Address',[validators.Length(min = 1, max=50)])
    user_password = PasswordField('Password',    [validators.DataRequired(),validators.EqualTo('confirm', message='Passwords must match')])
    confirm = PasswordField('Confirm Password')
```

The HTML code is

```
{% block body %}
    <h1>Registration</h1>
    {% from "includes/formhelpers.html" import render_field %}
    <form  method = 'POST'>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{render_field(form.name,class_= 'form-control')}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{render_field(form.email_address,class_= 'form-control')}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{render_field(form.user_password,class_ = 'form-control')}}
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
        {{render_field(form.confirm,class_ = 'form-control')}}
        </div>
        <p><input type ="submit" class = "btn-primary" value="Submit" onclick="myfunction()"></p>
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "there is no id supplied to the String field"?  WTForms fields always render an `id`, unless your `render_field` macro is interfering?

Comment: See in the above example can you tell me how can i call document.getElementById("demo") since i need to extract value from the form, validate, create a json and make a network call

Comment: There is no field called `demo` in the form or the html, so that isn't possible.

Comment: so you are saying that if i call  var value = document.getElementById("name"); I would get the text entered in the name field?

Answer (score 0):

If you open the html page and inspect the element, you will see that there is already a name and id defined to the element with the same name of you variable from StringField.

It means that you can find the text from the input fields like this:

```
var name = document.getElementById('name').value
```